# Converting String Date To Carbon Timestamp with Locale

Tags: php, laravel, timestamp, php-carbon

I have a date in string format, "Mon, 13 Feb 2017 09:30:00 GMT". I am trying to cast it to Carbon timestamp but I couldn't manage how. How can I use the GMT? What is the proper way?

```
$date = 'Mon, 13 Feb 2017 09:30:00 GMT';

Carbon::createFromFormat('D, d m Y H:i:s', $date)->toDateTimeString());
```

Comment: Use the right format and it will work

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You have not accounted for GMT ....`e`

Comment: Month should me `M` not `m`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to get the time_zone string for example `Europe/Paris` and pass it in as a parameter, for example:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('D, d M Y H:i:s e', $date, 'Europe/Paris')->toDateTimeString();
```

If you want GMT just use

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('D, d M Y H:i:s e', $date, 'UTC')->toDateTimeString();
```

It is one of the first things that comes up in the Carbon documentation...

```
Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $time, $tz);
```

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization